# Ubuntu upgrade of Tomcat: what effect on server.xml?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, apt

I'm using Ubuntu and its tomcat9 package. When time comes to upgrading tomcat (sudo apt upgrade tomcat9) what effect does that have on my custom/manual modifications on config files like server.xml?

Does apt-upgrade completely overwrite my custom config changes, does it try to merge them, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in `/etc/tomcat9` are not technically *"conffiles"* (according to `dpkg`), but are treated in the same way by the [maintainer scripts](https://sources.debian.org/src/tomcat9/9.0.43-1/debian/tomcat9.postinst/#L19) (cf. [ucf(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ucf/ucf.1.en.html) manpage).

You'll be offered the usual choice: use the maintainer's version or your version. Later on you can merge them yourself (the rejected version will be saved with a `.ucf-new` or `.ucf-dist` extension).